# Allow subdirectory in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a directory structure like so:

```
directory1
- directory2
- <other files I want to be hidden>
```

I want to allow the user access to directory 2, but disallow access to directory 1. For example:

http://website/directory1 = 404 / Forbidden

http://website/directory2 = Routes to directory1/directory2 and shows files.

I managed to lock out directory1 by using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(directory1) - [F,L]
```

But this obviously applies to subdirectory too and doesn't really help matters!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I've been pulling my hair out of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this may work. Although admittedly, I have some troubles with mod_rewrite as well,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^directory1
RewriteRule !^directory1/directory2 - [F,L]
```

or possibly, if mod_rewrite can handle these types of regexps, where `(?! )` is a non-matching group,

```
RewriteRule ^directory1(?!/directory2) - [F,L]
```